# Docker Container Dispatcher

Tags: image, docker, cloud, containers

I want to instantiate different containers from the same image to serve different requests and process different data.

Once a request is received by Docker, it has to instantiate a container (C1) from image (I), to work on a related dataset file D1.
For the second request, Docker has to instantiate a container (C2) from image (I) as well, to work on dataset file D2.
And so on ...

Does Docker have a built-in facility to orchestrate this kind of business or I have to write my own service to receive requests and start the corresponding containers to serve them?

Kindly provide your guidance on what is the best way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a serverless / function as a service framework. AFAIK Docker doesn't have anything like this built in. Try to take a look at [OpenFaaS](https://github.com/openfaas/faas) or [Kubeless](https://github.com/kubeless/kubeless). Both are frameworks that should help you get started with implementing your case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You mean that I need to use OpenFaaS along with Docker? Is OpenFaaS capable of receiving requests and starting the corresponding containers to serve them?

Comment: Yes, OpenFaaS uses Docker under the hood.